# Gamma Correction @ Power Law Transformation

Tags: opencv

I tried to do some simple gamma correction on an image. At first, I tried using Matlab then I apply it on opencv. But I get different result. Below is some of the code. Where does the code goes wrong?

In matlab:

```
for i=1:r;
    for j=1:c;
       imout(i,j)=constant_value*power(img_double(i,j),0.04);
    end
 end
```

In OpenCV:

```
for(int y=0; y<height; y++){
   for(int x=0; x<width; x++)
   {
        dataNew[y*stepNew+x] = constant_value*pow(dataNew[y*stepNew+x], 0.04);
   }
}
```

Where the image is an unsigned 8 bit, 1 channel image. Which part that I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you forgot to scale your image data in OpenCV to the interval [0,1]. In Matlab `im2double` does this for you automatically.
So for an 8 bit image something like this should work:

```
dataNew[y*stepNew+x] = 255 * constant_value*pow(dataNew[y*stepNew+x]/255.0, 0.04);
```

Comment: Why is there a 255 in front of constant value? Is it some kind of scaling back to 255 after doing division inside?

Comment: That is exactly what it is for.

Answer (score 1):

```
"""Function gamma( ) performs gamma(power transform) 
   logt() performs logarithmic transform
   histogram_equal( ) histogram equalization transform
"""

import numpy as np
def gamma(image,gamma = 0.5):
    img_float = np.float32(image)
    max_pixel = np.max(img_float)
    #image pixel normalisation
    img_normalised = img_float/max_pixel
    #gamma correction exponent calulated
    gamma_corr = np.log(img_normalised)*gamma
    #gamma correction being applied
    gamma_corrected = np.exp(gamma_corr)*255.0
    #conversion to unsigned int 8 bit
    gamma_corrected = np.uint8(gamma_corrected)
    return gamma_corrected


def logt(image):
    img_float = np.float32(image)
    max_pixel = np.max(img_float)
    #log correction being caluclated
    log_corrected = (255.0*np.log(1+img_float))/np.log(1+max_pixel)
    #conversion to unsigned int 8 bit
    log_corrected = np.uint8(log_corrected)
    return log_correctedenter code here
def histogram_equal(image):
    img_float = np.float32(image)
    #conversion 2D array to 1D array
    img_flat = img_float.flatten()
    #histogram genreation
    hist,bins = np.histogram(img_float,256,[0,255])
    #histogram cumulative distribution
    cdf = hist.cumsum()
    #to ignore values of cdf = 0
    cdf_masked = np.ma.masked_equal(cdf,0)
    num_cdf_m = (cdf_masked - cdf_masked.min())*255
    den_cdf_m = (cdf_masked.max()-cdf_masked.min())
    cdf_masked = num_cdf_m/den_cdf_m
    cdf = np.ma.filled(cdf_masked,0)
    cdf = np.uint8(cdf)
    img_flat = np.uint8(img_flat)
    img = cdf[img_flat]
    img = np.reshape(img,img_float.shape)
    return img
```